# Using shiftOut() with LSBFIRST bit order to send the data into the MAX7219 in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have the following code:

```
#define MAX7219_Data_IN 11
#define MAX7219_Chip_Select  9
#define MAX7219_Clock 13

void shift(byte send_to_address, byte send_this_data) 
{
    digitalWrite(MAX7219_Chip_Select, LOW);
    shiftOut(MAX7219_Data_IN, MAX7219_Clock, MSBFIRST, send_to_address);
    shiftOut(MAX7219_Data_IN, MAX7219_Clock, MSBFIRST, send_this_data);
    digitalWrite(MAX7219_Chip_Select, HIGH);
}

void init_max7219() //Setup of MAX7219 chip
{
    shift(0x0f, 0x00); //display test register - test mode off
    shift(0x0c, 0x01); //shutdown register - normal operation
    shift(0x0b, 0x07); //scan limit register - display digits 0 thru 7
    shift(0x0a, 0x0f); //intensity register - max brightness
    shift(0x09, 0x00); //decode mode register - No decode
}

void setup()
{
    pinMode(MAX7219_Data_IN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MAX7219_Chip_Select, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MAX7219_Clock, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(MAX7219_Clock, LOW);
    init_max7219(); //init MAX2719 chip

    shift(1, B01110111);
}

void loop() { }
```

I use shiftOut() to send the data into the MAX7219. I pass MSBFIRST as bit order parameter. It works fine. I use UnoArduSim and have the letter A in position 1 as expected. But I have problems with using LSBFIRST:

```
void shift(byte send_to_address, byte send_this_data) 
{
    digitalWrite(MAX7219_Chip_Select, LOW);
    shiftOut(MAX7219_Data_IN, MAX7219_Clock, LSBFIRST, send_to_address);
    shiftOut(MAX7219_Data_IN, MAX7219_Clock, LSBFIRST, send_this_data);
    digitalWrite(MAX7219_Chip_Select, HIGH);
}
```

Nothing is displayed on the seven-segment indicators. How to use the Least Significant Bit First correctly?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use LSBFIRST you need to change values passed to shiftOut. For example, change 0x0f (B00001111) to 0xf0 (11110000), 0x0c (00001100) to 0x30(00110000) so that the Least Significant Bit will be the first.

```
#define MAX7219_Data_IN 11
#define MAX7219_Chip_Select  9
#define MAX7219_Clock 13

void shift(byte send_to_address, byte send_this_data) 
{
    digitalWrite(MAX7219_Chip_Select, LOW);
    shiftOut(MAX7219_Data_IN, MAX7219_Clock, LSBFIRST, send_to_address);
    shiftOut(MAX7219_Data_IN, MAX7219_Clock, LSBFIRST, send_this_data);
    digitalWrite(MAX7219_Chip_Select, HIGH);
}

void init_max7219() //Setup of MAX7219 chip
{
    shift(0xf0, 0x00); //display test register - test mode off
    shift(0x30, 0x80); //shutdown register - normal operation
    shift(0xd0, 0xe0); //scan limit register - display digits 0 thru 7
    shift(0x50, 0xf0); //intensity register - max brightness
    shift(0x90, 0x00); //decode mode register - No decode
}

void setup()
{
    pinMode(MAX7219_Data_IN, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MAX7219_Chip_Select, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(MAX7219_Clock, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(MAX7219_Clock, LOW);
    init_max7219(); //init MAX2719 chip

    shift(0x80, B11101110);
}

void loop() { }
```